# Microsoft Access can't open a form from inside another form with doCmd.OpenForm

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm completely new to MS Access but not to databases. I have a form that is meant to open another form through a button and users are to add records to a target table through said form. The main menu fails to open my secondary form saying "recordset is not updatable". The table that is to receive the records is editable and I can go into it and manually add records so this doesn't seem to be the problem. If I click out of the error through the error handler menu I'm taken to the form that I expected to open, but it is read only-- I can't see it's properties sheet, design view, or even change the view at all. I looked at the VBA code on the main menu and it does use `doCmd.OpenForm "myForm", , , , , ,"New"`

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your form is actually named `myForm`? `New` is in filter argument but is not valid expression. Is form RecordSource table or query?

Comment: @June7 no that isn't the actual name, I just used that as the example. I just realized, the "New" is in the wong argument, it's meant to be  `doCmd.OpenForm "myForm", , , , , ,"New"` I will edit the question. The place where the records are to be saves is a table

Comment: I know records will be saved in table since there's nowhere else to save them. The question is: What is the form's RecordSource - table or query or SQL statement? What do you do with the `New` parameter?

Comment: @HansUp This whole set up was created years ago by someone else, I don't know what the "New" part is meant to be all about. I assumed it was a prompt to enter new records but I guess not. No, if I open myForm from the navigation pane it is also read-only.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions

Comment: Have you actually tried to open form in Design View? And yes, "NEW" is likely a "prompt" to enter new record. Most likely myForm uses this parameter to set itself in a mode to allow new record input only. You need to examine that code. It would refer to `OpenArgs`.

Comment: If this has worked in the past, what has changed? I meant open first to Design View directly from Navigation Pane, not after opening in Form View.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your form and click design view.  Add a button, click Cancel and name the button appropriately.  Than, right-click the button and click Build Event > Code Builder > OK.  Copy/paste the code below into the button click event.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "name_of_your_form"
End Sub
```

That should be all you need to do.  Sometimes I have seen Access do some really weird stuff.  If the steps I outlined here don't work, try doing a Compact and Repair to reset everything in your DB, and then add the button.